# How to create account name from LastName, FirstName in excel

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have a FullName column in Excel. The data in this column looks like LastName, FirstName.

I need to add a second column "AccountID" where I need to concatenate First Initial and lastName.

For example, Smith, John should be jSmith

I tried Left(fullname) but it will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FIND` command to find the location of the comma.  From there, you can use `MID` and `LEFT` to extract the first initial and last name.  Throw it all together, and you get:

```
=MID(A1, FIND(",",A1) + 2,1) & LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in cell A1, try this:

`=MID(A1,FIND(", ",A1)+2,1)&LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`

- *based on your format above*

Comment: I didn't know you could use & to concatenate. Unlimited POWEERRRR! <shoots lighting>

Comment: I'll +1 you though - he's got enough points. Here I've been using CONCATENATE.